# rewriting persian date in instead of normal Date format

Tags: database, c#-3.0

I have a datagrid which populated by some data from sqlserver.I have datetime filed that represent Georgian date,but i want to convert this to Persian by using PersianCalendar.
I wan some kind of conversion, that gets Georgian  date from database but when it comes to show on datagrid or some where else, it shows persian date.

Comment: Do you mean Gregorian instead of Georgian?

Comment: i mean Date some thing like 2007/05/02

Comment: @JonSkeet: I thought too it is called "Geogorian", derived from Georgia or something. Good catch!

Comment: @Isaac: Nope, it's named after Pope Gregory XIII, who introduced it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For formatting you need to use the appropriate [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) class, not the calendar - the names of persian cultures are `fa` or `fa-IR`, as can be seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx).

```
CultureInfo farsi = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
farsi.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new PersianCalendar(); 
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(1867, 1, 1);

Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString(farsi));
```

---

Update:

You can use the [`ItemDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound.aspx) event of the grid in order to format the date exactly as you want.

Comment: how can i use this in datagrid view or some other places in asp.net ?

Comment: @persian Dev - You need to set the thread culture of the app (UI thread if a winforms app), to the Persian culture. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

Comment: i used <globalization culture="fa-IR" /> but the date format does not change to persian format.

Comment: @persian Dev - Did you also set the `uiCulture="fa-IR"`?

Comment: use i have used it, but just changed the direction of error pages as i see.

Comment: @persian Dev - Are you using winforms or webforms or wpf?

Comment: i am using webforms, ASP.NET 3.5